# ¿Cómo firmo mensaje con SHA1whitRSA con llave publica?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sha1, rsa

Estroy tratando de firmar un mensaje con Sha1 y RSA,  el método descrito más abajo funciona y firma el mensaje, pero con la llaveprivada, si le trato de pasar la llavepublica, se peta con error, más abajo los detalles:

-- llave privada

```
 <RSAKeyValue>
      <Modulus>(...)schlL0=</Modulus>
      <Exponent>(...)</Exponent>
      <P>(...)a71w==</P>
      <Q>(...)Biw==</Q>
      <DP>(...)5Nmiw==</DP>
      <DQ>(...)LgzQ==</DQ>
      <InverseQ>(...)5rkQ==</InverseQ>
      <D>(...)9K2E=</D>
    </RSAKeyValue>
```

Pero necesito que funcione con una llave publica en xml como la siguiente:

-- llave publica

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>(...)chlL0=</Modulus>
  <Exponent>(...)</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Metodo:

```
public byte[] SHA1WithRSA_Signature(string msg, string privateKey)
        {

            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey);
            UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] originalData = encoder.GetBytes(msg);
            SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();

            byte[] signedBytes = RSA.SignData(originalData, sha1);
            return signedBytes;
        }
```

Si reemplazo la llave privada con la pública me arroja la siguiente exepción:

```
>System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'El conjunto de claves no existe
'
```

El método lo invoco de la siguiente manera:

```
byte[] byteArray = SHA1WithRSA_Signature("mensaje a cifrar", publica/privada);
string result = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
TexBox1.Text = result;
```

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYGS80-Joi8

Comment: Esto está relacionado: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generating-publicprivate-keys-in-c-sharp-and-net/

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias, los he revisado y probado, no se adaptan a lo que necesito pues la firma resultante no se parece a la firma de control que tengo, ya que estas generan las llaves aleatoriamente, no las toman del certificado o de una llave xml. Y pues estoy tratando de adaptar el código, hasta el momento, sin exito.

Comment: Pero para firmar tu debes usar la clave privada, no la pública. La publica se la proporcionas a tus clientes/usuarios para que tenga la seguridad que tu eres el que ha firmado pero no para que firmes tu. Al menos esto es lo que tengo entendido y lo que estamos haciendo en mi trabajo para nuestro cliente. ¿O me equivoco algo?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Es la segunda vez que me dicen eso, pero lo que pasa es que así me envío la contraparte la documentación, y pues como no se mucho de certificados, no tengo como refutarles. Me quedan dos opciones, 1° que no se trata de firmar sino de cifrar con la llave pública. 2° Ya con lo que tu me dices creería que ellos deben darme el certificado privado, pero no quieren por motivos de seguridad informática.

Comment: Nuevamente, puedes reformular tu pregunta, firmar el mensaje; lo firmas(clave privada) y lo envias, todo mundo puede ver el mensaje y su firma, si este sufre modificacion se puede verificar con la firma y llave publica. Si tu cifras un mensaje es con tu llave privada, aun que lo tengan accesso al mensaje nadie puede ententerlo (esta cifrado) si quieres recuperar el mensaje necesitas tu llave privada. Para firmar el documento necesitas saber donde termina el mensaje y comienza la firma. es recomendable usar un documento xml para marcar el inicio del mensaje y la firma

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev está en lo correcto. Con claves asimétricas cuando encriptas usas la clave publica para encriptar y la privada para desencriptar. Cuando firamas un documento, firmas con la clave privada y verificas con la clave pública. Fijate que de esta forma la clave privada siempre permanece privada y la clave pública es la que se divulga.

Comment: aqui referencias a lo que deseas [xml signature](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) y [Cryptography.Xml net](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Evgeni Enchev, Miguel Zarate y Juan Gracias a todos, entonces ellos son los que están completamente desorientados en esto y de paso me desorientan a mi, voy a revisar los enlaces para poder entender este tema y así decirles que me están pidiendo imposibles.

Comment: @Vulpex, fíjate en el código que has publicado - pasas la clave **privada** al RSA para acceder a tu almacén de claves (donde previamente has instalado el certificado con el que vas a firmar) y luego llamas `SignData` para firmar. Accedes a tu almacén con cla clave privada, ¿cómo vas a acceder a tu almacén, al certificado, con la clave pública? No tiene lógica. Cualquiera podría hacerlo, vaya seguridad ¿no? Pues eso, espero que lo soluciones con tu cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez se aclare mejor con un ejemplo, como te decia para firmar un mensaje es mejor saber donde empieza el mensaje y la firma, asi se puede verificar extrayendo las partes.
   Por ejemplo usando xml se pude crear el mensaje, crea el documento y guardalo con extension .xml  ; En el codigo se firma el documento usuando un certificado pfx este se puede generar facilmente en windows busca algun tutorial.

Cuando lo ejecutes revisa el documento ya firmado analiza  la seccion Signature, alli veras que se esta agregando la firma del documento y la clave publica, de esta manera
usando alguna libreria el cliente puede verificar la integridad del mensaje usando la Llave publica.
Agregue dos metodos de verificacion uno con llave privada y otro con publica el segundo metodo es el que tu necesitaras para verificar que nadie ha modificado el mensaje, (ejemplo si al documento firmado le cambias una letra al mensaje, el metodo verificarFirmaPublica dara como salida = false)
 A continuacion el codigo.

mensajeUsuario.xml

```
<Memo>
  <Usuario>Roger</Usuario>
  <Mensaje>ya compre las cervezas para el viernes</Mensaje>
</Memo>
```

En tu clase program agrega lo siguiente:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //parametros
            string pathXmlDocument = @".\mensajeUsuario.xml";
            string pathXmlSignedDocument= @".\mensajeUsuarioSigned.xml";
            string pathCertificate = @".\zarateCert.pfx";
            string certPassword = "zarateTest";

            FirmarDocumento(pathXmlDocument, pathCertificate, certPassword, pathXmlSignedDocument);


           var isValido=    VerificarFirmaPRivateKey(pathXmlSignedDocument, pathCertificate, certPassword);

            var esValidoPubica= VerificarFirmaPublicKey(pathXmlSignedDocument);

        }

        private static void FirmarDocumento(string pathXmlDocument,string pathCert,string passCert, string pathXmlSignet)
        {


            XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
            documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

            SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

            var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
            firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
            firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

            //digest info
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            reference.Uri = "";
            firmado.AddReference(reference);

            reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

            firmado.AddReference(reference);

            // with the public key will be added in the signature part. 
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
            firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;


            firmado.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();
            documentXml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(documentXml.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
            //guardando salida.
            documentXml.Save(pathXmlSignet);
        }

        private static bool  VerificarFirmaPRivateKey(string pathXmlSigned,string pathCert,string passCert)
        {
            var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
            var key = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
            XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
            documentXml.Load(pathXmlSigned);

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(documentXml);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = documentXml.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

          return   signedXml.CheckSignature(key);
        }

          private static bool  VerificarFirmaPublicKey(string pathXmlSigned)
        {

            XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
            documentXml.Load(pathXmlSigned);

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(documentXml);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = documentXml.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");

            signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

          return   signedXml.CheckSignature();
        }
```

para la clase Helper:

```
  public class RSA_helper
    {
        //public static RSA GetRSA(string certPath, string certPassword)
        //{
        //    var certificado = GetX509Certificate(certPath, certPassword);
        //    RSA rsaKey = ((RSA)certificado.PrivateKey);
        //    return rsaKey;
        //}


        public static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate(string certPath,string password)
        {
             X509Certificate2  certificado= new X509Certificate2();
            certificado.Import(ReadFile(certPath), "zarateTest", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            return certificado;
        }
        internal static byte[] ReadFile(string fileName)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            int size = (int)f.Length;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            size = f.Read(data, 0, size);
            f.Close();
            return data;
        }

    }
```

Comment: ¿qué pass le pasas al método `GetX509Certificate` del Helper? Debe ser la privada. El problema no es **cómo** firmar un mensaje (el formato pdf, txt, xml) no es relevante. El problema es **cómo** firmar **sin clave privada**. Y esto es lo que yo opino que no se puede hacer.

Comment: Si se revisa la pregunta es como firmar el mensaje, usando RSA, el algoritmo es firmas con clave Privada, verificas con llave publica. Ahora el documento pfx contiene la llave privada y publica, se encuentra cifrado usuando el password.  Los documentos con extension .cer solo contienen la llave publica y otros metadatos.

Comment: Pero el tiene solo la clave publica, no la privada.

Comment: Si es lo que no ha comprendido bien Vulpex,  un certificado es para validar la Identidad de una Entidad (empresa, persona, sitio...) cada Entidad o Persona solo puede firmar sus documentos  en caso de Vulpex debe hacer que cuando la aplicacion se ejecute en el cliente , tome el certificado instalado en la maquina del Cliente (la ubicacion del certificado como parametro en el config de la aplicacion).

Comment: @MiguelZarate, Muchas gracias, ya se me empieza a clarificar el tema un poco más, aunque todavía me encuentro dando vueltas, porque la verdad que ya no se que quiere esta gente. ¿compa, sería mucho abusar de su amabilidad y le puedo dar a conocer la documentación de dicho webservice, como para que me digas, algo como bien es usted tiene que hacer esto o aquello, es firmar o encriptar?

Comment: Pues comparte una liga de tu documentacion en otro comentario, en algun tiempo libre yo o alguno de la comunidad podra dar su opinion al respecto.

Comment: @MiguelZarate :: Para poder realizar el llamado al servicio debe cargar la librería jrsasign en Postman para realizar el **firmado digital** con algoritmo `SHA1withRSA` tenga en cuenta la variable firma se genera por el código que se encuentra en la pestaña `pre-request-script` que básicamente toma la llave privada que está en `llavepem`, toma el cuerpo del mensaje, lo firma con el algoritmo `SHA1withRSA` y posteriormente lo coloca en base 64 para incorporarlo en el header enviado. continua...

Comment: @MiguelZarate Esto es de como hacerlo en Postman, lo adapté a C# y funciona en pruebas, pero ellos para pruebas me enviaron la llave privada, en producción no la dan, solo me dan dos .cer `root.cer` y `intermed.cer ` y ninguno de estos tienen la llave privada.