# Firmar un string con algoritmo RSA SHA1 sign desde C#

Tags: c#, sha1, rsa

estoy intentando firmar un string con el algoritmo RSA SHA1 usando la llave privada que me dan para consumir una API.

He intentando varias cosas y ninguna me ha dado un resultado correcto, ya que al intentar hacer un request a la API me retornan un codigo de error de que la firma es invalida o mal generada.

La idea es : 
1) Concatenar los datos que recibo.
2) Firmarlos con el algoritmo que me especifican y la private key otorgada.
3) Convertir a string estos datos y enviarlos

Lo que he probado hasta ahora fue:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] datosAFirmarByte = ByteConverter.GetBytes(datosAFirmar);

RSAParameters rsaParametros = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
rsaParametros.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(privada);
rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParametros);

try
    {
      byte[]signedbytes=rsa.SignData(datosAFirmarByte,CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
      return Convert.ToBase64String(signedbytes);
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
```

Mi sospecha (y que no he encontrado nada en internet de como hacerlo), es que le estoy pasando mal la private key al CryptoProvider.

Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Saludos.

Comment: Como aclaración, tengo un string definido como **privada** para agarrar la private key desde ahí

Comment: revisa esta respuesta para firma, que te parece tu cadena este en una estructura xml para que facilmente identifiques los elementos checa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276122/consulta-por-firma-digital-en-un-documento-xml-con-c/276149#276149

Comment: tambien revisa esta otra pregunta y la respuesta que di al respecto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273619/c%c3%b3mo-firmo-mensaje-con-sha1whitrsa-con-llave-publica/274563#274563